# Google Cloud Data Fusion - Dynamic arguments based on functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

Good morning all,

I'm looking in Google Data Fusion for a way to make dynamic the name of a source file stored on GCS. The files to be processed are named according to their value date, example: `2020-12-10_data.csv`

My need would be to set the filename dynamically so that the pipeline uses the correct file every day (something like this: `${ new Date(). Getfullyear()... }_data.csv`

I managed to use the arguments in runtime by specifying the date as a string (`2020-12-10`) but not with a function.

And more generally is there any documentation on how to enter dynamic parameters with ready-made or custom "functions" (I couldn't find it)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a readymade workaround, you can give a try "BigQuery Execute" plugin.

Steps:

1. Put below query in SQL

> select cast(current_date as string) ||'_data.csv' as filename
> --for output '2020-12-15_data.csv'

2. Row As Arguments  to 'true'
3. Now use the above arguments via ${filename} wherever you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try this and tell you if it works as desired. It's still surprising that Fusion did not provide a feature for this.